# How to Export Data from mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql, export

I use numberic to store my leave status in mysql database. If the number is 1 then the leave is approved , if the number is 2 then the leave has been rejected . Now the problem i am facing now is i don't know how to convert the numberic into string using php. I wan to get the word approved and rejected in the .csv file that i have exported . Now it only show the number 1 and 2 .

```
$query ="SELECT tblemployees.FirstName,tblemployees.LastName,tblemployees.EmpId,tblemployees.Gender,tblemployees.Phonenumber,tblemployees.EmailId,applyleave.id,applyleave.LeaveType,applyleave.FromDate,applyleave.duration,applyleave.ToDate,applyleave.descr,applyleave.PostingDate,applyleave.sta,applyleave.adminRemark,applyleave.AdminRemarkDate from applyleave inner join tblemployees on applyleave.employeeID=tblemployees.EmpId";
 $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
 {

  $output .= '
   <table class="table" bordered="1">  
                    <tr>  
                        <th>No</th>  
                        <th>Employee ID</th>  
                        <th>Employee Name</th>  
                        <th>Employee Email</th>
                        <th>Employee Contact Number</th>
                        <th>Leave Type</th>  
                        <th>From Date</th>  
                        <th>To Date</th>
                        <th>Duration</th>
                        <th>Reason</th>  
                        <th>Leave Status</th>  
                        <th>Request Date</th>  
                        <th>Admin Remark</th>
                        <th>Admin Remark Date</th>

                    </tr>
  ';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $sta='.$row["sta"].';
    if($sta==1){
        $status="Approved";

    }
    if($sta==2){
        $status="Rejected";
    }
   $output .= '

                    <tr>  
                        <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["EmpId"].'</td>  
                        <td>'.$row["LastName"].' '.$row["FirstName"].'</td>  
                        <td>'.$row["EmailId"].'</td>  
                        <td>'.$row["Phonenumber"].'</td>  
                        <td>'.$row["LeaveType"].'</td>  
                        <td>'.$row["FromDate"].'</td> 
                        <td>'.$row["ToDate"].'</td>  
                        <td>'.$row["duration"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["descr"].'</td>  
                        <td>'.$status.'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["PostingDate"].'</td>  
                        <td>'.$row["adminRemark"].'</td> 
                        <td>'.$row["AdminRemarkDate"].'</td>  

                     </tr>
   ';
  }
$output .= '</table>';
  header('Content-Type: application/xls');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='. date('Y-m-d') .' Leave Balance.xls');
  echo $output;
```

Comment: Where do you define `$sta`?

Comment: oh , I did't define it . How am i going to define it ? Using SESSION ?

Comment: I should define it inside the while loop right ?

Comment: What is in `$sta`?

Comment: Well, you actually don't need to define a new variable. Just compare `$row['sta']`.

Comment: @El_Vanja How to compare sir ?

Comment: You are doing it already. Just replace `$sta` with `$row['sta']`.

Comment: Did you got any error?

Comment: @El_Vanja Yes thanks for your help. I have got the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is that you are appending dots `.`. to the variable and using single quotes. Variable on single quotes are not interpreted and their value is not going to be returned.

```
//Your code
$sta='.$row["sta"].'; // This will save on $sta ( .$row["sta"]. ) because you are using single quotes.

// Update to
$sta=$row["sta"];  // you don't need quotes or dots in the variable
```

Also the if statement I will change it to something like:

```
if($sta==1){
    $status="Approved";
}else if($sta==2){
    $status="Rejected";
}else{
    $status = "Not Defined";
}
```

To take in consideration other values like nulls etc.

[PHP Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)